# Set Windows 2008 Server wallpaper for all users

Tags: windows-server-2008, desktop

I'm logged on as the Administrator and want to set a specific wallpaper image for all users. I've done it before on 2003 Server but forget where. I think it was somewhere inside the **Local Security Policy** manager but I can't find it. Does anyone know where to enable the active desktop then set the wallpaper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

run gpedit.msc

Navigate to User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Desktop > Desktop

Active Desktop settings are under here.

Double click Desktop Wallpaper, select Enabled, Type in the path to your jpg/or bmp file under Wallpaper Name.

Comment: I did this, but I still see no wallpaper even after loggin off and logging back in.